# Java Dom4j SAXReader and XMLWriter result in multiple linefeeds

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

I need to read a XML file (if exists - if not then I will create the file), modify some tags and write the xml back. I am doing this with

```
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(userFile);
    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    Document document = reader.read(in);

    Element root = document.getRootElement();
    ...
```

and writing back with

```
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(userFile, getFormatedXML(document).getBytes());

    ...

    private String getFormatedXML(Document doc) {
    try {
        String encoding = doc.getXMLEncoding();

        if (encoding == null)
            encoding = "UTF-8";

        Writer osw = new StringWriter();
        OutputFormat opf = new OutputFormat("  ", true, encoding);
        XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(osw, opf);
        writer.write(doc);
        writer.close();
        return osw.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return "ERROR";
}
```

The problem is, that after each writing back one additional line feed will be created. If I switch the argument of outputFormat from true to false, no linefeeds at all will be written.

Is there an easy way to go around this problem?

Thanks a lot
Hauke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to write formatted XML in Java is using the `javax.xml.transform` packages, like this:

```
 TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
 transfac.setAttribute("indent-number", 2);
 Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
 trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
 trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
 trans.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
 Result result = new StreamResult(System.out);
 trans.transform(new DomSource(document), result);
```

Instead of `System.out`, use a `FileOutputStream` for your destination file.

By the way, there are a number of gotchas in the code you present:

```
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(userFile, getFormatedXML(document).getBytes());
```

This isn't safe for different encodings because you've used String#getBytes() which uses the default platform encoding and could easily result in an XML document with the incorrect encoding heading.

`XMLWriter` is a com.sun implementation-specific class which isn't portable across JDKs. (That's less likely to be a problem for you)

Comment: Thank you very much. That is working much better. But I needed to change two things in order to work properly:

1) transfac.setAttribute("indent-number", new Integer(2)); --> I needed to remove that because I got an IllegalArgumentException: Is not supported
2) trans.transform(new DocumentSource(document), result); --> DomSource Object wasn't in my classpath, but DocumentSource was. Maybe I am using a different version.

Thanks a lot!